# DSP library compatible with QT?

Tags: c

I have checked [this](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/1571/optimized-ansi-c-libraries-for-dsp) and [this](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/1571/optimized-ansi-c-libraries-for-dsp) Question in this site very much similar to my question. But I want to know are they Qt compatible? I want to start learn developing DSP application in Qt framework so I want some library compatible with Qt so that it can later be translated into Qtpython also? Can we use same libraries with Qt as it is? Will it make effect on changing data types to and from this library to QtObject? I am new to DSP and Qt. so may be the question seems silly.

Comment: This is more of a programming question, so it should be posted on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com). With that said, your choice of GUI toolkit shouldn't drive your selection of a library used for signal processing. If your user interface design is that coupled to the processing that you're doing, then you have a bad software architecture. Secondly, if you want to eventually use these DSP libraries from PyQt, then you'll want to determine whether they have Python bindings already, or you'll need to write them yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Not quite the answer you requested, but I think the sanest thing(OOP wise)  to do in most of the situations is to have the backend of the application separated from the frontend.

You could create a standalone library(either static or dynamic) for your dsp code and separate it from the QT code.

This way your DSP code would be independent of the frontend you are using.
You could switch from QT to anything else(wxWidgets/GTK+ etc) and your DSP functions inside the lib would remain the same.

Comment: Exactly how I do it.  I created a separate library and I then just use it in my QT apps.  This way I also haven't made my DSP library depend on QT conventions at all.