# Implementation of the filter function (Matlab) C/C++

Tags: matlab, filters, filter-design, filtering, c++

I am trying to apply some filtering in C/C++ code, I have designed an algorithm using `Matlab` and it works well, so now I am moving it to native code.

I am interested in the `filter` function.
In my matlab script it is used as follows.

```
[y_blk, fir1_state] = filter( h, 1, x.*c, fir1_state );
```

Where the `h` argument is coefficients generated by `firpm` function.

I have tried to find any implementation, but unfortunately no results.

I would be very grateful if someone could provide an implementation of this function

Or maybe there is an existing implementation of this function in some library.

Thanks

Comment: The `filter` function is implemented in a large number of open-source packages, such as octave and SciPy.

Comment: look at https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/1571/optimized-ansi-c-libraries-for-dsp  and also Google "signal processing c library"

Comment: You can find a lot of implementations of a FIR Filter on the INTERNET.
I wanted to write the code but I already found it on the below link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14997850/fir-filter-implementation-in-c-programming

Answer (score 1):

FIR filtering is an operation whose implementation hugely benefits from utilization of architecture-specific instructions, compiler intrinsics, etc. Hence, if your only goal is to get a performant FIR algorithm, you should try to find a dsp library specifically for your target architecture. Those are most likely written in assembly language with a C interface and you can expect an orders-of-magnitude better performance than you would achieve with a generic C implementation of a transversal FIR.

If the latter is exactly what you're looking for - a generic FIR implementation in C - let me point you towards https://iowegian.com/. They offer a commercial filter design software called ScopeFIR. You can download and install a free trial version of it (no registration). In the program directory, you can find a source file "FirAlgs.c" that offers a variety of well-documented FIR implementations. It's written for MSVC but should be portable to basically anywhere without hassle.